# Not getting data from firebase in redux method using componentdidmount

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Hi I am new to reactjs and new to redux.

I was trying to get data from. I have created a collection called categories in the firebase database and am trying to get the values from there.

[image]

I am calling the function in Home fragments in my app through Component did mount function.

Here is my HomeFragments.js

```
export class HomeFragment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.categories === null) {
      this.props.loadCategories();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="md" fixed>
        <AppBar position="static" color="white">
          <Tabs
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
            aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
          >
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <BannerSlider
          Images={[{ image: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" }]}
        />
        <HorizontalScroller />
        <StripAdView />
        <GridView />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export const CategoryTab = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Avatar
        alt="Remy Sharp"
        variant="square"
        src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
      />
      <Typography variant="body2">Title</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: state.categories,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadCategories: () => dispatch(loadCategories()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeFragment);
```

I am calling the method in categoryAction.js:

```
export const loadCategories = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firestore
      .collection("CATEGORIES")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log("querysnapshot:", querySnapshot);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

};

In this I am calling a console.log(querySnapshot) which should give me the value in the console. However I am not getting any value in the console.

Here is my App.js:

```
const DEFAULT_REDUCER = (initstate, action) => {
  return {
    key: "HELLOW WORLD",
  };
};

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    DEFAULT: DEFAULT_REDUCER,
    categories: categoryReducer,
  })
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Authenticated>
            <Dashboard />
          </Authenticated>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Authenticated nonAuthenticated={true}>
            <Login />
          </Authenticated>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" render={() => "404 Not Found!"} />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong and why Am I not getting the value can somebody help?

I am getting this warning:

[image]

My Home fragment is called in the dashboard component;

Here is the dashboard component:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import HomeFragment from "../Fragments/HomeFragment";
```

return (

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <CssBaseline />
  <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
    <Toolbar>
      <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
        <img src={logo} height="40px" style={{ marginRight: "16px" }} />
        <Typography variant="h4" display="inline">
          My Mall Admin
        </Typography>
      </Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
  <Drawer
    className={classes.drawer}
    variant="permanent"
    classes={{
      paper: classes.drawerPaper,
    }}
  >
    <Toolbar />
    <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
      <List>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Home />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Home" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Category />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Categories" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Phonelink />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Products" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <ShoppingCart />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Orders" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Settings />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Setting" />
        </ListItem>
        {/* ****Submenu***** */}
        <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Settings />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Setting" />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <StarBorder />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Collapse>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <StarBorder />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="AnotherStarred" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Collapse>
        {/* ****Submenu***** */}
        <Divider />
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <PowerSettingsNew />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Logout" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  </Drawer>
  <main className={classes.content}>
    <Toolbar />
    <HomeFragment />
  </main>
</div>
```

);

I have added the Home fragment at the bottom of the clipped drawer

Comment: Can you include the code where you have used `HomeFragment` as well as in where is it used in **JSX** plus how have you imported it ?

Comment: Hi I have included the code for the homefragment. It is at the bottom of the drawer component in the dashboard

Comment: the dashboard component I have called in app.js

Comment: Can you also show the statement which imports it ?

Comment: Added the import statements. Its basically

Comment: import HomeFragment from "../Fragments/HomeFragment";

Comment: In your `mapStateToProps` what comes if you do `console.log(state)`  before return statement ? Specifically what's the value of `state.categories` ?

Comment: I am doing console.log(state) but I am not getting any console values for some reason

Comment: state.categories should ideally return the categories that are available in the firebase firestore

Comment: Hi, just to be sure, the issue is still ongoing?